# What am I doing wrong on using JSON Decoder

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to decode a JSON, however, my breakpoint goes straight to the Catch Statement instead of print the decode data. What am I doing wrong? What I tried was create another Struct where I unpacked all the Array of Data from JSON, I already did it on previous projects, but for this one something else is wrong. For this project I gotta parse the following properties:

- name
- abv
- url_image

***JSON***

```
[  
    {  
        "id":1,
        "name":"Buzz",
        "tagline":"A Real Bitter Experience.",
        "first_brewed":"09/2007",
        "description":"A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.",
        "image_url":"https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png",
        "abv":4.5,
        "ibu":60,
        "target_fg":1010,
        "target_og":1044,
        "ebc":20,
        "srm":10,
        "ph":4.4,
        "attenuation_level":75,
        "volume":{  
            "value":20,
            "unit":"liters"
        },
        "boil_volume":{  
            "value":25,
            "unit":"liters"
        },
        "method":{  
            "mash_temp":[  
                {  
                    "temp":{  
                        "value":64,
                        "unit":"celsius"
                    },
                    "duration":75
                }
            ],
            "fermentation":{  
                "temp":{  
                    "value":19,
                    "unit":"celsius"
                }
            },
            "twist":null
        },
        "ingredients":{  
            "malt":[  
                {  
                    "name":"Maris Otter Extra Pale",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":3.3,
                        "unit":"kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Caramalt",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":0.2,
                        "unit":"kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Munich",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":0.4,
                        "unit":"kilograms"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "hops":[  
                {  
                    "name":"Fuggles",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":25,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"start",
                    "attribute":"bitter"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"First Gold",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":25,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"start",
                    "attribute":"bitter"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Fuggles",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":37.5,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"middle",
                    "attribute":"flavour"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"First Gold",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":37.5,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"middle",
                    "attribute":"flavour"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Cascade",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":37.5,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"end",
                    "attribute":"flavour"
                }
            ],
            "yeast":"Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™"
        },
        "food_pairing":[  
            "Spicy chicken tikka masala",
            "Grilled chicken quesadilla",
            "Caramel toffee cake"
        ],
        "brewers_tips":"The earthy and floral aromas from the hops can be overpowering. Drop a little Cascade in at the end of the boil to lift the profile with a bit of citrus.",
        "contributed_by":"Sam Mason <samjbmason>"
    },
    {  
        "id":2,
        "name":"Trashy Blonde",
        "tagline":"You Know You Shouldn't",
        "first_brewed":"04/2008",
        "description":"A titillating, neurotic, peroxide punk of a Pale Ale. Combining attitude, style, substance, and a little bit of low self esteem for good measure; what would your mother say? The seductive lure of the sassy passion fruit hop proves too much to resist. All that is even before we get onto the fact that there are no additives, preservatives, pasteurization or strings attached. All wrapped up with the customary BrewDog bite and imaginative twist.",
        "image_url":"https://images.punkapi.com/v2/2.png",
        "abv":4.1,
        "ibu":41.5,
        "target_fg":1010,
        "target_og":1041.7,
        "ebc":15,
        "srm":15,
        "ph":4.4,
        "attenuation_level":76,
        "volume":{  
            "value":20,
            "unit":"liters"
        },
        "boil_volume":{  
            "value":25,
            "unit":"liters"
        },
        "method":{  
            "mash_temp":[  
                {  
                    "temp":{  
                        "value":69,
                        "unit":"celsius"
                    },
                    "duration":null
                }
            ],
            "fermentation":{  
                "temp":{  
                    "value":18,
                    "unit":"celsius"
                }
            },
            "twist":null
        },
        "ingredients":{  
            "malt":[  
                {  
                    "name":"Maris Otter Extra Pale",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":3.25,
                        "unit":"kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Caramalt",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":0.2,
                        "unit":"kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Munich",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":0.4,
                        "unit":"kilograms"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "hops":[  
                {  
                    "name":"Amarillo",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":13.8,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"start",
                    "attribute":"bitter"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Simcoe",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":13.8,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"start",
                    "attribute":"bitter"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Amarillo",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":26.3,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"end",
                    "attribute":"flavour"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"Motueka",
                    "amount":{  
                        "value":18.8,
                        "unit":"grams"
                    },
                    "add":"end",
                    "attribute":"flavour"
                }
            ],
            "yeast":"Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™"
        },
        "food_pairing":[  
            "Fresh crab with lemon",
            "Garlic butter dipping sauce",
            "Goats cheese salad",
            "Creamy lemon bar doused in powdered sugar"
        ],
        "brewers_tips":"Be careful not to collect too much wort from the mash. Once the sugars are all washed out there are some very unpleasant grainy tasting compounds that can be extracted into the wort.",
        "contributed_by":"Sam Mason <samjbmason>"
    },
```

***Network Folder***

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
func getApiData(){
    guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers") else {
        print("URL Error")
        return
    }
    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in

        if response.data == response.data{
            do{
                let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Data.self, from: response.data!)
                print(decoder)
            }catch{
        print(error)
            }
        }else{print("API Response is Empty")}

        }
}
```

***Model Folder***

```
import Foundation

struct Data:Decodable {
    let cervejas : [Cerveja]
}

struct Cerveja:Decodable{
    let name:String?
    let abv:String?
    let image_url:String?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
let models = try JSONDecoder().decode([Cerveja].self, from: response.data!)
```

Change the `Cerveja` class to

```
let abv:Double?
```

after successful decoding access them like

```
for model in models {
    print(model.name)
}
```

Comment: Hello Ratul, still going to Catch statement. When the error is printed that's what I got: 
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "cervejas", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"cervejas\", intValue: nil) (\"cervejas\").", underlyingError: nil))
(lldb)

Comment: i've updated the answer a bit, can you try updated code ?

Comment: Worked perfecly! So, why I don't needed to create the struct unpacking the data?

Comment: How do I access the properties? Like, decoder.name, decoder.abv

Comment: your json is returning an array of `Cerveja` object, so treat the it like an array, i've updated the array. Mark the answer as accepted, if it serve your purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Just a quick question, once I got the properties value how can I use them on another screen?

Comment: Current context of this question does not provide enough clue for the question `how can I use them on another screen?`, it requires a separate question to be answered